# Probability problem; if sum and product are not divisible by number

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Out of set of numbers {10,11,...,100} three are being chosen randomly. Find these probabilities:

1. At least one out of three are divisible by 6
2. Exactly two are not divisible by 4
3. Their sum is not divisible by 4
4. Their product is not divisible by 3

So to choose three numbers out of 91 I can do in $\binom{91}{3}$ ways. First probability I solved this way:

$\frac{\binom{15}{1}\binom{76}{2}+\binom{15}{2}\binom{76}{1}+\binom{15}{3}}{\binom{91}{3}}$

Since there are 15 numbers divisible by 6 i have 3 options that 1 is divisible two are not, 2 are divisible 1 is not and all of 3 are divisible.

Second probability:
$\frac{\binom{69}{2}22}{\binom{91}{3}}$
Since there are 22 numbers that are divisible by 4 i subtracted 22 from 91 and got numbers that are not divisible by 4 from which I chose 2 numbers and the third I chose from those 22.

I do not know how to solve third and fourth and also I am not sure if the first two probabilities are correct.

Comment: First comment: there are $91$ numbers to choose from, not $90$.

Comment: I will correct that thank you. The logic is right on the other hand?

Comment: Well, for the first problem I would start with the probability the none of the numbers is divisible by $6$ and subtract that from $1$. In the second case choose $1$ out of the $23$ that are divisible by $4$ and $2$ out of the $68$ that are not. If the product is not divisible by $3$ then none of the factors is, so choose $3$ of the $58$ numbers. The third problem is harder but for an elementary problem like this you will be typically inundated with answers in a few minutes.

Comment: Hint: For the 4th you have to ensure each of the three numbers is not divisible by 3

Comment: There are $25 - 2 = 23$ numbers divisible by $4$ in the set, so $91 - 23 = 68$ are not divisible by $4$.

Comment: 3) The three numbers are each of the form $4k_i + r_i$ where $r_i = 0,\pm 1,$ or $2$.  The sum is divisible by $4$ if $r_1+r_2=-r_3$ or if $r_1+r_2= 4- r_3$...... 4) The product is divisible by $3$ if at least one of the two is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I took the time to work out the hard part. Here is a table:
$$\begin{array}{cccc|c|c}0&1&2&3&\text{Number}&\text{Total}\\ \hline
23&22&23&23&&\\ \hline
3&0&0&0&\binom{23}{3}&1771\\
1&1&0&1&\binom{23}{1}\binom{22}{1}\binom{23}{1}&11638\\
1&0&2&0&\binom{23}{1}\binom{23}{2}&5819\\
0&2&1&0&\binom{22}{2}\binom{23}{1}&5313\\
0&0&1&2&\binom{23}{1}\binom{23}{2}&5819
\end{array}$$
The fist $4$ columns represent the congruence classes $\pmod4$ and we see how many from each class is in the set to form a number divisible by $4$. The fifth column counts the number of ways such a selection may be made and the sixth column is the numerical result. Adding up the results in the fifth column we see that there are $30360$ ways to sum to $4$, with probability
$$\frac{30360}{\binom{91}{3}}=0.249907$$
But we want the probability that the sum is **not** divisible by $4$ which is
$$1-0.249907=0.750093$$
In the third problem, since there are $30$ numbers in range divisible by $3$ we need to select $3$ out of the $61$ that are for a probability of
$$\frac{\binom{61}{3}}{\binom{91}{3}}=0.296251$$
Since there are $15$ numbers in range that are divisible by $6$, we get
$$1-\frac{\binom{76}{3}}{\binom{91}{3}}=1-0.578672=0.421328$$
for the first problem. In the second problem, we need $1$ divisible by $4$ and $2$ not, so we get
$$\frac{\binom{23}{1}\binom{68}{2}}{\binom{91}{3}}=0.43128$$

Answer (score 1):

3. Divide the numbers in set of 4 groups which are of the forms 4k (23 numbers), 4k+1(22 numbers), 4k+2 (23 numbers)and 4k+3 (23 numbers). Find the cases when sum is divisible by 4.

(4k,4k,4k) which is equivalent to C(23,3);(4k,4k+2,4k+2) C(23,2)C(23,1);(4k,4k+1,4k+3);(4k+1,4k+1,4k+2);(4k+3,4k+3,4k+2) etc

Use exclusion